# nginx and express router get+post request issue

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am trying to setup the 2 node/express sites behind nginx. I think I have tried all possible solutions that I found in the forums, but they only work partially for me.

What I want to achive is:
- one domain with 2 node/express apps
1.) node.dev/site3
2.) node.dev/site4

This works all okay for the main index file, however selecting any button/Route I get a 404 error.

Here is the nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root  /var/www/node.dev;
    server_name node.dev;
    index index.htm index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/node;
    charset utf8;
    sendfile off;
    location /site3/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8088/;
        #rewrite ^/site3/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /site4/ {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    #rewrite ^/site4/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

and this is my Express route setup:

```
var express   = require('express');
module.exports = function(app) {
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/ping', function(req, res){
      res.send("pong!", 200);
});
router.get('/walk/:walk_name', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("walk!", 200);
});
router.get('/walk', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("No walker!", 200);
});
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular     will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
app.use('/', router);
}
```

accessing the site with //node.dev/site3 returns the index file as expected, however clicking on WALK for example, it should return //node.dev/site3/walk, but instead it returns http://node.dev/walk and with that a 404 error.

I can't do any changes in the node/express app. Is there any way to achieve this with the nginx configuration.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `proxy_pass` to 127.0.0.1 not 0.0.0.0. The former means "localhost" the latter means "any host". While you might listen on "any ip", you want to connect to a /specific/ IP.

There may be another issue, but this might help.

Comment: I tried so set it to localhost and to 127.0.0.1 but the issue is still the same. It just does not resolve any POST/GET request.